# Apache Nifi-registry deployment using git repo as flow repo

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

We would like to use Nifi registry with git as storage engine. In that case, i modified providers.xml and i was able to save the flows there.

Challenges:

1. There is no 2 way sync. We can only save the flows modified by Nifi user but if we modify the flow directly in git location, it will not be reflected on nifi registry
2. There is no review or approval process for Nifi registry. A user has to login to nifi-registry server, create a branch and issue a pull request.
3. As a workaround, we can delete the database file ( H2) and restart the nifi resgistry.
4. Lastly, everything should be automated in CI/CD like what we do for regular maven project.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the git storage is mostly to let user visualize the differences through tools like git hub, or any other tools that can support diffs, plus by pushing to a remote you also get a remote backup of the flow content. It is not meant to be modified outside of the application, just like you wouldn't bypass an application and go right into it's database and start changing data.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.  In that case, i can use REST API calls for make changes to STAGE/PROD registry based on changes in DEV registry. We would like to automate the process, thats why these questions.

Comment: @SunilS how did you end up solving this ? There needs to be an input from developers raising PRs in order for making changes to STAGE/PROD.